# Elasticsearch - change dynamic field index to not_analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a rails application with dynamic field into my models. those fields can have some special charaters (ex: '/') and i want tho facet onto those fields. **I don't want to  change defaults of dynamic mappings but i want them to be not_analyzed.**

Here's my mapping :

```
GET /items/_mapping

{
 .
 .
  "dynamic_field_1": {
    "type": "string"
  },
 .
 .
}
```

is there a way to update mapping to this?

```
GET /items/_mapping

{
 .
 .
  "dynamic_field_1": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  },
 .
 .
}
```

Eventually go back to 'analyzed' :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dynamic mapping like this when you create the index:

```
    POST /items/_mapping
    {
      "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
          "dynamic_templates": [
            {
              "string_template": {
                "mapping": {
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "match": "*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

You can also specify the non-dynamic fields in there.